# Calculating the value returned by NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey using OSX system calls

Tags: ios, macos, posix, stat, xattr

For the question to make sense, let me guide you through the whole test case, so please bear with me.

Let's create a file.

> echo 0 > ~/SAMPLE

This makes a simple file that is 2 bytes in size (echo appends new line by default, and that doesn't hurt the example).

> stat -f "%b %Z" ~/SAMPLE

The output:

> 8 2

As expected, this file allocated 8 blocks and is 2 bytes in size (Get Info in Finder tells us that is it 2 bytes long and 4k on disk, which is 8 blocks * 512 bytes per block), so it is all good.

Now let's add an attribute, a resource fork in particular:

> xattr -w com.apple.ResourceFork 000000 ~/SAMPLE

Let's call stat again:

> stat -f "%b %Z" ~/SAMPLE

The output:

> 16 2

After adding the resource fork attribute, the file system allocated 16 blocks for this file.

> ls -l@ ~/SAMPLE

The output:

> com.apple.ResourceFork    6

**To sum it up**: We added 6 bytes to the resource fork and this file now allocates 16 blocks (from only 8 before adding the resource fork), has the content of only 2 bytes and the resource fork has 6 bytes.

If we run this file through the NSURL API, we get this:

> NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"~/SAMPLE"];
>
> [url getResourceValue:&size forKey:**NSURLFileSizeKey** error:nil]; // output: 2
>
> [url getResourceValue:&size forKey:**NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey** error:nil]; // output: 4096
>
> [url getResourceValue:&size forKey:**NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey** error:nil]; // output: 8192

So my question is, if were to use just the system calls (bash or the system API), how would we get 4096, the result for the **NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey** key?

The NSURLFileSizeKey is easy - we can just use ls -l for example, also for NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey - we can use the number of blocks from stat (16) and multiply by 512, but how do we get the value for **NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey**, which is 4096 in this case?

From my understanding, it would be the value returned by the **NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey** key if we were to delete the resource fork attribute, but how do we get that value using system APIs or bash?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey** refers to allocated space for the data fork only, just as **NSURLFileSizeKey** refers to the size of the data fork only.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think too, but I am not sure how to obtain that info programmatically?

Comment: I'd just link against Foundation and use `-[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:]`

Comment: So unfortunately I am not allowed to do that, I need to use some system-level APIs (constraints of the project), I just need to implement the equivalent functionality.

Comment: Maybe stat the resource fork and subtract its block count from the file's total block count?

Comment: Tried that as well, the number of blocks is the same for the ~/SAMPLE and ~/SAMPLE/..namedfork/rsrc - both 16 :(